# What word means "things that can't coexist togther"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am writing an essay and I wanted to say that the things I like about a large university and the things I like about a small university can't exist together. For example the small supportive community comes at the expense of meeting new people every day, etc. 
a word like irreconcilable maybe ?
The sentence says 
"... the best features of each university seemed ............. (can't coexist together)"

Thank you!

Comment: They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You're a genius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *[incompatible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/incompatible)*

> (Of two things) so opposed in character as to be incapable of existing together:
>   *cleverness and femininity were seen as incompatible*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

Consider **antinomic**.

> Definition: contradiction or opposition between one statement,
>   principle, rule, etc., and another;
>
> Example: *The choice of that solution was driven by the concern to
>   reach a compromise between requirements that sometimes were
>   antinomic*.